# Windows shared segment in clang

Tags: c, windows, clang

I'm porting a Windows C code written for MSVC to be compatible with gcc and clang. I have this snippet of code to declare a variable in a shared segment:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.shr,RWS")
#pragma data_seg(".shr")
volatile int g_global = 0;
#pragma data_seg()
```

I know that the gcc equivalent in Windows is:

```
volatile int g_global __attribute__((section("shr"), shared)) = 0;
```

In response to a comment of course I already tried the same attribute with clang but the "shared" key is ignored.
What is the working equivalent for the clang compiler in Windows?

Comment: Clang is for many parts GCC compatible. Have you tried the same attribute as for GCC?

Comment: I tried but the "shared" key is ignored and I can't find how to signal that the segment has to be shared